# Hello, New to programming and to C, 2 weeks in, bug in my code?

Tags: c

The problem is that if I add a digit < 6 but > 0 it should display the message "You did not win the lottery". However, it keeps telling me my value is not within the range.

Where did I make the mistake?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()

{
  char cSelection = '\0';
  int iRandom = 0;
  srand(time(NULL));

  iRandom = (rand() % 5) + 1;

  printf("\n Welcome to this guessing game! Please enter your guess from 1 to "
         "5 now!\n\n");
  scanf("%c", &cSelection);

  if (isdigit(cSelection) == 0) /*Indien het getal geen numeriek waarde heeft
                                   wordt deze lijn uitgevoerd*/
  {
    printf("Yours is not a digit\n");
  } else if (cSelection ==
             iRandom) /*Indien het getal gelijk is aan het random getrokken
                         getal is de lotto gewonnen*/
  {
    printf("You won the lotto!\n\n");
  } else if (cSelection > 5 || cSelection < 0) /*Getal is niet <6 en >0; getal
                                                  mag de waarde 1,2,3,4 & 5
                                                  hebben*/
  {
    printf("Number is not between 0 and 5. Winning number = %d\n", iRandom);
  } else if ((cSelection < 6 || cSelection > 0) ||
             cSelection != iRandom) /* Getal heeft een waarde van 1,2,3,4 of 5
                                       maar is niet gelijk aan het 'winnende'
                                       random getal*/
  {
    printf("You did not win the lotto!\n");
  } // end if
} // end main function
```

Comment: First you should format & indent this mess properly. Spacesarethereforgoodreasons.

Comment: When posting code on SO (and first when trying to find out the issue on your own), try to get rid of the non-relevant code and get to the essence. You'll be surprised how fast you'll be able to find a solution to your problem.

Comment: You are reading input into a character, but comparing it to integers.  '1' != 1

Comment: Thanks @Trevor Hickey. I changed it all. But now it can't tell me whether I entered a digit or not.

 if (isdigit(iSelection) == 0) 
    {
            printf("Yours is not a digit\n");
            }

Comment: @JeroenReuns Yes.  You now need to look at how isdigit works.  Although, I suggest not even using isdigit anymore.  If you have an int, it's clearly made up of digits.  The isdigit function is intend to be used on chars.

Comment: change to `if (isdigit(cSelection) == 0)
  {
    printf("Yours is not a digit\n"); return 0;
  }
  cSelection -= '0';
  if (cSelection ==
             iRandom){`

Comment: @TrevorHickey , You are right, better not to use it. However my book included this assignment. And since I know there must be a way I would love to find it!!

Comment: Do not compare boolean functions with `0` or `1`. That makes your code harder to read. Just use them like a natural language expressions: `if ( isdigit('1') ) ...`.

Comment: And use markup to highlight code or names, etc.

Answer (score 1):

6 is an int not the character 6. Change 6 to `'6'`, etc. `'6'` represent the value that encode the character 6 that the user pressed. 6 is just the number 6.

Answer (score 0):

You're comparing characters to numbers.

```
} else if (cSelection ==
             iRandom)
```

You're comparing `cSelection`, a character such as `'1'` (numeric value
49), to iRandom, an int such as `1`. That will always be false, for
these values.

```
} else if (cSelection > 5 || cSelection < 0)
```

Again, character versus number. The character will always be > 5.

Comment: I changed it all to integers, so now it compares integers to integers. However now it can't tell me whether I entered a digit or not. if (isdigit(iSelection) == 0) { printf("Yours is not a digit\n"); }

Answer (score 0):

The character you read from scanf is an ASCII character.
In ASCII, the character zero is represented by the number 48. 1 is 49, and so on.

You need to subtract 48 from the cSelection and it will work.

you can perform this subtraction after the isdigit() test, to maintain it's functionality

Comment: Simply substracting 48 is not portable at all. Think e.g. [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) where character positions are completly different from ASCII.

Comment: No, but It's a good starting point to explain whats going on and why. one can then expand on it and use something like " cSelection -= '0' ", atoi(), strtol(), and so on.